# Input/output error on new USB hard drive

Tags: linux, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, raspberry-pi

I got a brand new Toshiba USB hard drive. Attempting to format it on my Raspberry Pi 3 errored and returned an input/output error, so I used a tool on Windows to set it to ext4. Now that I've reconnected my drive, it still returns errors from a simple mkdir and ls (with and without sudo)

```
stijn@raspberrypi:/mnt/mv $ mkdir documents
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘documents’: Input/output error
stijn@raspberrypi:/mnt/mv $ ls
ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error
```

Note: an USB SSD I have attached to the Pi works perfectly, but another - albeit older - USB HDD has had many issues on it and became fully unreadable, whilst still working fine on other devices.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SuperUser. Please include relevant output from `dmesg`/journal/syslog ...

Comment: Here it is! https://pastebin.com/shTdVBnh @0xC0000022L

Comment: Which tool have you used in Windows which created a EXT4 file system? Have you tried formatting it to NTFS? Once done, run chkdsk (check disk on it) then I would use Linux to create the EXT4 file system.

Comment: I've used MiniTool Partition Wizard. Sadly formatting to EXT4 wasn't possible using the Pi, I can however try to use WSL or a Docker container to format it. Both drives had healthy results from CrystalDiskInfo however @vssher